# Add elements in a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to extract elements from a list and add them into another new list.How can I do this-

```
L=[['abc',18],['bcd',19],['def',20]],
nth1(Count,L,List1),
nth1(2,List1,Value),
**NOW I WANT TO PUT THIS Valie in another new list.So finally new list will have 
   New=[18,19,20]**
```

How can I keep adding elements in a new list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)/3 and friends

```
?- L=[['abc',18],['bcd',19],['def',20]], findall(E,member([_,E],L), R).
L = [[abc, 18], [bcd, 19], [def, 20]],
R = [18, 19, 20].
```

Answer (score 2):

The same could be achieved with a maplist:

```
?- maplist(nth1(2), [['abc',18],['bcd',19],['def',20]], R).
R = [18, 19, 20].
```

Is the argument order of `nth/3` a coincidence?

Comment: This is not the same, it's better ; works with variables ; ensures that we have lists. Think of `[[abc,18]|nonlist]`

Comment: Argument order: It is the same as of `arg/3`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your instructor wants you to work out the recursive solution yourself, you could simply say something like this (given your example data):

```
slurp( []         , []     ) .
slurp( [[_,X]|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- slurp(Xs,Ys) .
```